# Internal Server Error after Fusion Auth Upgrade to v 1.9.1

Tags: fusionauth

I have attempted to upgrade a production environment fusion auth instance from version 1.6.x to 1.9.1 unfortunately after the database migration we are presented with error 500 page when browsing to the app.

I have taken a look at the logs which shows the following error:

> Sep 24, 2019 4:16:03.726 PM ERROR
>   com.inversoft.scheduler.LogAndRetainFailureHandler - The scheduled
>   service [class io.fusionauth.api.service.cache.ThemeCacheLoader]
>   failed but will be re-run.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid
>   message value for theme   at
>   io.fusionauth.api.domain.CachedTheme.loadProperties(CachedTheme.java:40)
>     at io.fusionauth.api.domain.CachedTheme.(CachedTheme.java:24)
>     at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
>     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>     at
>   io.fusionauth.api.service.cache.ThemeCacheLoader.load(ThemeCacheLoader.java:34)
>     at
>   io.fusionauth.api.service.cache.ThemeCacheLoader.run(ThemeCacheLoader.java:40)
>     at
>   com.inversoft.scheduler.InjectableRunnable.run(InjectableRunnable.java:37)
>     at
>   com.inversoft.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.(DefaultScheduler.java:74)

(I have truncated the log output on purpose, if needed I can edit question with full log)

I have also looked in the themes table which contains two entries. The first has a very large JSON object string literal in the data column the second just has any empty JSON object i.e. "{}".

I am reaching out as hopefully this is a simple data issue? Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that can occur when you have a custom theme defined prior to upgrade.

A fix will be available shortly in version 1.9.2, a work around is described in the above linked GitHub issue and provided below as well.  https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/306

Workaround:

1. For each theme other than the default FusionAuth theme
2. Use the Retrieve Theme API
3. Set a value for the `defaultMessages` such as empty string
4. Update the theme using the Update Theme API

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/themes

Comment: as always you're an absolute star! Following your steps easily fixed our issue. 
For the benefit of others: With this issue the API is still up and running so we used  Postman to retrieve the default FusionAuth theme then taking the `defaultMessages` prop from there we used the PUT put request to update our custom theme to get things going.

**Thanks again for all your hard work, swift responses and support!**

Comment: Thanks @TomBean your feedback is appreciated!